# How to retrieve first not null query set Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

I'm trying to get unique, not null data in my model.

Ex : I have Django Model Query set data like
{{id : 1,organisation :None},{id : 1,organisation :Google},{id : 2,organisation :None}}

Expected Result :
{{id : 1,organisation :Google},{id : 2,organisation :None}}

Is there any way to get the first, not null value in Queryset based on the id,organization key?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share your model.

Comment: You can add a filter like this to your queryset. `filter(organization__isnull=False)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`queryset = Model.objects.filter(organisation__isnull=False).values('id', 'organisation')`

This query should work, place your `Model` name under `Model` in the example

Comment: It's not working for my requirement, for example data is like = {{id : 1,organisation :None},{id : 1,organisation :None}} it should return {id : 1,organisation :None}

Comment: you wanted `not null value in Queryset based on the organization key`, right?

Comment: I need ** First Not Null Value** based on id & Organisation as key ( Id will have always value, Organisation key will be null in some cases ), I need to get only 1 query set which contains, for example, if none of the  organization_id having value for an ID it should return {id:1, organisation:None}

Comment: `instance = Model.objects.first()` I think this will help you.
`{'id': instance.pk, 'organisation':instance.organisation}`